# HTML Table with rowspan and colspan not aligning as expected

Tags: html, html-table

I have been racking my brain with this for a while and not a single of the fixes I have come across on SO have helped me, so I am reaching out for some help now.

I have a table that is built up of a collection of row pairs that should be combined in a specific way. Below is the html structure I have been using.

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td rowspawn="2">a</td>
      <td rowspawn="2">b</td>
      <td rowspawn="2">c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td rowspawn="2">g</td>
      <td rowspawn="2">h</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">def</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My understanding is that the cells "d" "e" "f" should have the cell "def" directly under them, however I have the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szgak2qz/1/).

I believe I should see something like this

```
-------------
| d | e | f |
-------------
| def       |
-------------
```

This doesn't make any sense to me, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: typo : near rowspawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a mistake in "rowspawn" (it's "rowspan")

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">a</td>
      <td rowspan="2">b</td>
      <td rowspan="2">c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td rowspan="2">g</td>
      <td rowspan="2">h</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">def</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: OH MY GOD! I feel like a melon. I have been dealing with this for a few days now. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: haha no problem, it happens to the best of us. Besides "rowspawn" sounds kinda cool ;)